# How to know if incoming variable is of a specific enum type?

Tags: typescript

I have a class that has an overloaded constructor, where an input argument can be either a number, an instance of a certain class type, or a value of certain enum type:

```
class Person { name: string; };
enum PersonType { Type1, Type2 };

constructor(id: number);
constructor(person: Person);
constructor(personType: PersonType);
constructor(arg: string | Person | PersonType)
{
    if (typeof arg === "number") { /* do number stuff */ }
    else if (arg instanceof Person) { /* do Person stuff */ }
    else if (typeof arg === "PersonType") { /* do PersonType stuff */ }
    else throw new MyException("...");
}
```

Now, apparently, when I execute the "typeof arg" in case an enum value is supplied, that evaluates to "number", and not "PersonType", so my code can't work as expected.
Using instanceof for an enum type doesn't work either, as it's meant for object types only.

So, can anyone tell me how I can get to know when my input argument is of a specific enum type? What am i missing here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> So, can anyone tell me how I can get to know when my input argument is of a specific enum type?

It's not possible. Look at the compiled code for the `enum`:

TypeScript:

```
enum PersonType { Type1, Type2 }
```

JavaScript:

```
var PersonType;
(function (PersonType) {
    PersonType[PersonType["Type1"] = 0] = "Type1";
    PersonType[PersonType["Type2"] = 1] = "Type2";
})(PersonType || (PersonType = {}));
```

At runtime, the enum `PersonType` is just a JavaScript object used as a map. Its members are strings and numbers. The enumeration of your example contains:

```
{
  "Type1": 0,
  "Type2": 1,
  "0": "Type1",
  "1": "Type2"
}
```

So, the members `Type1` and `Type2` in the enumeration, are true numbers:

```
console.log(PersonType.Type1) // 0
```

Comment: OK, thanks, that explains it.I'll have to live with that then

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of wrokaround you can use:

```js
enum PersonType { Type1 = 'Type1', Type2 = 'Type2' }
```

To test if the incoming arg string is of type PersonType, you can use this check:

```js
if (Object.values(PersonType).includes(arg)) {...}
```

This check returns `true` if `arg == 'Type1' or 'Type2'` and can also support any new added entries to the enum since we are looping on all possible values of the ennum

Answer (score -1):

It is possible with string enums

You can declare an enum like so:

```
export enum PageNumber {
    CURRENT = "CURRENT",
    TOTAL_PAGES = "TOTAL_PAGES ",
    TOTAL_PAGES_IN_SECTION = "TOTAL_PAGES_IN_SECTION ",
}
```

Then you can check it against string:

```
if (typeof child === "string") {
```

Intelli-sense seems to not flag errors

[image]

It also seems to be aware of the enum type too:

[image]